# Notation on page $176$ of Jech: $\sigma^L$

Tags: notation, set-theory

Perhaps I'm not looking closely enough, but I'm not able to find where Jech has used the notation $\sigma^L$ before, as he does on page $176$. For those without the text that might be able to figure out, here's the quote:

Theorem-$13.3:$ $L$ is a model of $ZF$.

We show that $\sigma^L$ holds for every axiom $\sigma$ in $ZF$....

This is probably really obvious, but from someone who doesn't know a lot of model theory and jumped from Chapter-$6$ to Chapter-$13$, the notation is confusing me. We want to show each axiom holds in $L$. Is this what they mean?

Comment: Page 161: The *relativization* of sentence $\sigma$ to model $L$?

Comment: Yes, this is what it means. To say that $\sigma^L$ holds means that $L\models\sigma$. To say that it holds in a theory (such as ZF) means that the theory proves that it holds. The precise definition of $\sigma^L$ given in the book avoids having to introduce the satisfaction relation $\models$ for proper classes, which would add some technical complications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about Definition 12.6 of Page 161 with the $\in$ symbol omitted?
[image]